# Using this script on an input tag but it removes the entered text slightly after a letter is entered

Tags: javascript, html, input, src, masking

```
function formatPhoneNumber(value) {
        if (!value) return value;
        const phoneNumber = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
        const phoneNumberLength = phoneNumber.length;
        if (phoneNumberLength < 4) return phoneNumber;
        if (phoneNumberLength < 7) {
          return `(${phoneNumber.slice(0, 3)}) ${phoneNumber.slice(3)}`;
        }
        return `(${phoneNumber.slice(0, 3)}) ${phoneNumber.slice(
          3,
          6
        )}-${phoneNumber.slice(6, 9)}`;
      }

function phoneNumberFormatter() {
        const inputField = document.getElementById('phone-number');
        const formattedInputValue = formatPhoneNumber(inputField.value);
        inputField.value = formattedInputValue;
      }
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input onkeydown="phoneNumberFormatter()" id="phone-number" />

    




    <script src="home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix the issue of when an user enters an incorrect type of input such as a letter for it to not be procceced and displayed on the input but instead ignore it until a number is to be entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a keydown `event` object into your formatter and block that event if it contains a letter.

For example, in your `html`:

```
<input onkeydown="phoneNumberFormatter(this, event)" id="phone-number" />
```

and then in your `js`:

```
const MAX_LEN = 14;

function isControl(value) {
  return value === 'LeftArrow' || value === 'RightArrow' || value === 'Backspace';
}

function isDigit(value) {
  return value >= '0' && value <= '9';
}

function formatPhoneNumber(value, event) {
  if ((!isDigit(event.key) && !isControl(event.key)) ||
    (isDigit(event.key) && value.length === MAX_LEN)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return value;
  }
  console.log(value.length);
  if (!value) return value;
  const phoneNumber = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  const phoneNumberLength = phoneNumber.length;
  if (phoneNumberLength < 4) return phoneNumber;
  if (phoneNumberLength < 7) {
    return `(${phoneNumber.slice(0, 3)}) ${phoneNumber.slice(3)}`;
  }
  return `(${phoneNumber.slice(0, 3)}) ${phoneNumber.slice(
    3,
    6
  )}-${phoneNumber.slice(6, 9)}`;
}

function phoneNumberFormatter(event) {
  const inputField = document.getElementById('phone-number');
  const formattedInputValue = formatPhoneNumber(inputField.value, event);
  inputField.value = formattedInputValue;
}
```

This approach will allow you to block the incoming keydown `event` and prevent `input` from showing it.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: This solution works but the last number changes when I type again

Comment: @JaneSmith would you like just to ignore any new character if input reaches max length?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @JaneSmith I've updated the answer with the length limit. I've also added some logic to allow control keys. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `'input'` event instead.

```js
document.getElementById('phone-number').addEventListener('input', phoneNumberFormatter);
```

Note that you will have to adjust the lengths you are checking for in the `formatPhoneNumber` function.